# Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

I am trying to dockerize my Angular ASP.NET Core WebAPI.
I have the following dockerfile created:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2.105 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY src/Fightplan_v1/Fightplan_v1.csproj ./
# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Fightplan_v1.dll"]
```

The structure of my project is as follows:

[image]

The WebApi project is located inside the "src/Fightplan_v1" folder.

I am able to build my image fine using the following command:

```
docker build -f fp.dockerfile -t test .
```

When I try to run the image using:

```
docker run -it test
```

I get the following error:

```
Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from:
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
```

The project is build on `dotnet core 2.2.105` so what this ofcourse tells me is that the image does not have the necessary dotnet core sdk installed. But as you can see in the dockerfile the sdk version I am downloading is `2.2.105`.

I read [here](https://github.com/aspnet/aspnet-docker/issues/322) that the `ENTRYPOINT` is case sensitive and I have checked this several times now.
If I do a `dotnet publish` locally and go into the `bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2` I will find a DLL file called "Fightplan_v1.dll". Which is the name I assume I need to add to `ENTRYPOINT`?

I might just be missing some other steps here but I am not sure what.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I had to add in an extra `COPY . .` statement after `RUN dotnet restore` to include all the `.cs` files. I'll answer my own question with the solution when possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing a `COPY . .` in the `dockerfile` after `dotnet restore`. I guess I was missing some `.cs` files in order for it to be compiled correctly.

The working `dockerfile` ended up looking like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2.105 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY src/Fightplan_v1/Fightplan_v1.csproj ./
# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Fightplan_v1.dll"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your docker file should be like this

```
ENTRYPOINT ["Fightplan_v1.dll"]
```

Or if this not work try this

```
CMD ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:$PORT dotnet Fightplan_v1.dll
```

Comment: Thank you for your response - this didn't work though unfortunately - I am getting "C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"Fightplan_v1.dll\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown."

Comment: Running the second option gives me the same error as initially.